# Counting characters in words in a C++ console application

Tags: c++, histogram

This is the problem that I am attempting to solve:

Ask the user to enter a bunch of words, as many as they want, until they enter a 0. After
that, count how many times each letter appears across all the words, and print out a list of each letter and how many times it appears.  Example:

```
Enter word> hello
Enter word> lemon
Enter word> goodbye
Enter word> 0
Letter: h appears 1 times
letter: e appears 3 times
...
```

So far I have to put all the words together, and have made comparisons. The problem lies in that, after all the words are put together, and 0 is input, I cannot count each invidual character within the combined string. I did some research, and I've read that to perform this you need vectors, but i do not understand how to use them.

I've been trying at it for a week to get it right, but to no avail. C++ is sort of different from all the other language I have learned (at least for me).

Comment: Some idea: maintain an array/vector of size 256 for 256 possible characters (I am assuming ASCII), at each time when you read a new word, you iterate over that word, increment the counter for corresponding characters.

Comment: He should look into using an associative array. An ordered map or unordered map would work better than a vector/array here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), with the characters as key and the counter as value. For each string you read, just iterate over it and increase the value corresponding to the character in the map.

This way you don't actually need to store the words.

Comment: Just one thing about filling the map. I feel like OP will fill it one by one by hand. Just iterate over ascii table characters(those that you need) and fill it in that way :)

Comment: He may want to prefer an ordered map here to allow for easy manipulation of the results, such as sorting by frequency.

Comment: @PaulRenton Nice reputation. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah part of me wishes I could stay at 666!